# Не отображаются картинки в шаблоне

Tags: django, шаблоны

Всем привет!
Возникла такая проблема: при правильной (вроде как) настройке путей для статических файлов и медиа-файлов картинки в шаблоне не прогружаются.

Пути в настройках:

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "assets")
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
)

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "media")
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

Кстати, папки `assets`, указанной в `STATIC_ROOT` не существует. Вообще проект изначально работал без этой переменной, но после её добавления уже нельзя было ее убрать - проект просто не запускался.

Картинки подгружаются только в том случае, если к пути в шаблоне добавить `/static/media/`:

```
<img class="d-block w-100" src="/static/media/{{ image.url }}" alt="">
```

Но мне кажется, что это как-то криво всё выглядит, разобраться не получается.

Помогите, кто-нибудь, пожалуйста! 
Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Файлы изображений, которые относятся к моделям и могут быть загружены каким либо пользователемляются статическими файлами. Это медиа файлы. Для них есть параметры `MEDIA_ROOT` и `MEDIA_URL`.

Сделайте следущее:
- для статики выполните команду `collectstatic`
- для MEDIA_URL добавьте доступ к файлам с серверной стороны (nginx, apache) или на время отладки (при DEBUG = True)  через [django'вскую систему раздачи статики](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/static-files/#serving-static-files-during-development)

Comment: добавила в `url.py` строку 
`urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)`и выполнила команду `python manage.py collectstatic`
после этого просто появилась папка `assets` и туда все склонировалось,
а в путях в шаблоне убрала `/static/media/` и картинки так и не подгружаются :С

Comment: добавьте еще `static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)`

Comment: Всё равно нет :( не подбавляются к пути `/static/media/`
, а в браузерной консоли так и выводится: `http://127.0.0.1:8000/model_images/apple.jpg 404 (Not Found)`

Comment: скиньте ваш urls.py и settings.py на данный момент